# Stupid rendering time on PS (3D layer)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I feel wrong, but it's just as simple as this: two words, extruded text, simple flat white material, default lightning, nothing special. Rendering time on 3D Studio Max-VRay about 1 minute (2K size image). Rendering time on 3D layer Photoshop CC, one hour and a half? Seriously? Even for a 1000x600px image?

Am I doing something wrong? Is it really so slow?
Thanks

Comment: You have to remember that Photoshop uses a toy renderer the real rendering engines like vray, mentalray, brasil, renderman are really optimized by top CS people.